# When python-vlc plays some HTTP stream, get_time won't work as expected

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc

This is my code. Its role is to output the current playing time of the video.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import vlc
import os

def MediaPlayerTimeChanged(args, hwnd):
    print args.u.new_time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    instance = vlc.Instance()
    player = instance.media_player_new()
    vlc_events = player.event_manager()
    vlc_events.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerTimeChanged, MediaPlayerTimeChanged, None)
    media = instance.media_new("http://pic.qiantucdn.com/58pic/video/27/34/30/27343023_69.mp4")
    player.set_media(media)
    player.play()
    os.system("pause")
```

But it does not output the current playback time as expected, only output the same time repeatedly.

```
250
250
250
250
250
250
250
250
250
......
```

The same problem occurred with the Videolan official player.
[image]

Comment: I don't know what `pause` is doing but the video runs fine on my box it runs for a little over 8 seconds.

Comment: Is it accurate for its output time?

Comment: Running locally (8813ms), remotely (8811ms).

Comment: If you don't mind, can you tell me your VLC Media Player version or LibVLC version? Thank you very much.

Comment: vlc 2.2.2 | libvlc5 version 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 | libvlccore8 version 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4  and  vlc.py  __version__ = "2.2.6100"

Comment: Thank you very much. After I changed the VLC Media Player version, the program worked as expected successfully